# What distinct matching routines do exist?

Tags: r, causality, matching, treatment-effect, confounding

In a seminar paper I'm discussing all possible matching routines. It turned out that there are quite many of them. Now I am looking for several answers:

First, I discovered that some routines happen to be combined with each other, e. g. Nearest neighbor- and Subclass matching (since there's an extra R-package I do not count e. g. CEM for a 'combination'). Probably there are more combinations applied in practice, or any of my list are also a special case of an other. Could anybody tell me something about that?

Second, are there eventually more routines existing of whose I'm not aware of?

Third, since I'm programming in *R* I found all the routines in the *MatchIt* package, except those with the *. Is it possible that these routines are outdated (e. g. there's a package *radiusmatching* but does not work anymore for R 3.x) or synonyme to an other routine listed?

Here is a list of my findings:

- Coarsened exact matching (CEM)
- Full matching
- Genetic matching
- Interval matching*
- Kernel matching*
- Mahalanobis distance matching
- Nearest neighbor matching w/ subclasses
- Nearest neighbor matching w/ replacement
- Nearest neighbor matching w/ replacement and caliper
- Optimal matching
- Propensity score matching*
- Radius matching*
- Subclass matching

*Note:* This post is not intended to discuss dis-/advantages of any routine.

Thanks for any helpful contributions.

Comment: Since the site has a tag for propensity scores with 199 threads I wonder what steps you have taken to find out about the ones you asterisk? Telling us would help avoid people duplicating your efforts.

Comment: I want to find out sth. about applied  _combinations_ of them, or _routines_ _undiscovered_ from me, or _synonymes_ – just as I stated in my post. PSM is one of 13 routines, for the case I am counting right. Thanks.

Comment: There is also local linear/polynomial matching, and, a bit further afield, inverse probability weighting. You can think of the first as an extension of kernel matching, and of matching as approximation of IPW.

Comment: MatchIt implements propensity score matching. Matching occurs on a variable or set of variables; propensity scores are just one of those variables any of the above procedures could be used with, so propensity score matching is not a distinct form of matching.

Comment: There's also https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/designmatch/index.html

Comment: There's also Elizabeth Stuart's [list](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~estuart/propensityscoresoftware.html).